# How to change a single words colour in a String in Swift

Tags: string, swift, dictionary, parse-platform

So as some context, I have a dictionary which holds some custom error messages, based on the error code returned by Parse. You can see one below:

```
var parseErrorDict: [Int:String] = [

    203: "This email address \(emailTextField.text) is already registered." 

]
```

What I would like, is the email address that will be populated to be a different colour or to be in Bold. Is this possible?

Fairly new to Swift so please explain or help clearly :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an attributed string to edit different parts of the string. You would first break down the string into three parts in your case, the start, middle and end. Then you can add attributes to these three parts, e.g. make the middle part (email address) red, then you can append the three parts back together again:

```
// The first part of the string should be mutable as parts will be appended to it
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This email address ")

// Here we specify the attribute that is will be applied to the middle part
var attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
var attributedStringEmail = NSAttributedString(string: "someone@somewhere.com", attributes: attributes)

// The end part
var attributedStringEnd = NSAttributedString(string: " is already registered.")

// Combine the three parts
attributedString.appendAttributedString(attributedStringEmail)
attributedString.appendAttributedString(attributedStringEnd)

// Give the label its text
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: I noticed in the combine the three parts section, you didn't add the first attributedString, you only combined the middle and the end...?

Comment: on the last part, adding it to the label, how do i do this in my situation? As there isn't any label for me to add it to?